# I'm unable to find tabular format result in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm unable to get output as tabular format.

```
DECLARE
    prev    VARCHAR2(10) := 'sysdate+1';
    tdy     VARCHAR2(10) := 'sysdate';
    v_dt    VARCHAR2(10);
    result  resultset;
BEGIN
    v_dat :=
        CASE
            WHEN trunc(sysdate) = trunc(currnet_date) THEN
                tdy
            ELSE prev
        END;

    WITH 
     yesterday AS (
        SELECT
            src_dim_id,
            rec_count
        FROM
            tab_total_last_updated
        WHERE
                to_char(dw_insert_datetime, 'mm-dd-yy') = CASE
                                                              WHEN TRIM(to_char(v_dt, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')) =
                                                              'MONDAY' THEN
                                                                  to_char(v_dt - 3, 'mm-dd-yy')
                                                              ELSE
                                                                  to_char(v_dt - 1, 'mm-dd-yy')
                                                          END
            AND table_type = 'EXT'
    )
    SELECT
        *
    INTO result
    FROM
        yesterday;
    RETURN result;
END;
```

I'm trying to pass value sysdate into v_dt as per the condition but I'm unable to proceed with my code please help on this one.

Comment: Does that code compile?  You haven't specified the definition for `resultset` so by default you'd get compilation errors.  But perhaps that is a user-defined type.  You also appear to have a host of errors related to using strings for dates incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have many typos in your code `v_dat` should be `v_dt`, `current_date` is misspelt.

You cannot `RETURN` a result as you are using an anonymous PL/SQL block and not a function.

Also, you probably do not want to use PL/SQL and just want an SQL query (and do not need the sub-query factoring clause):

```sql
SELECT src_dim_id,
       rec_count
FROM   tab_total_last_updated
WHERE  dw_insert_datetime >= CASE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                             WHEN 0 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3 -- Monday
                             WHEN 6 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2 -- Sunday
                             ELSE        TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
                             END
AND    dw_insert_datetime <  CASE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                             WHEN 0 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2 -- Monday
                             WHEN 6 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 -- Sunday
                             ELSE        TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                             END
AND    table_type = 'EXT';
```

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve using:

```sql
v_dt := CASE
        WHEN trunc(sysdate) = trunc(current_date)
        THEN SYSDATE
        ELSE SYSDATE + 1
        END;
```

But you appear to be trying to correct for differences between the dates on the server and the client. In which case either:

- Use `CURRENT_DATE` throughout the above code instead of `SYSDATE`; or
- Use a specific time zone and replace `SYSDATE` with, for example, `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.